# R - Delete lines following specific conditions

Tags: r, delete-row

I am actually working on a school project on R. I would like to delete observations from my database that contain a specific character in a specific variable.

More precisely, I am building a boxplot to compare two variables, the year and the genre of movies. But in my .csv file, some rows contain a ";" in the title (of the movie), and it totally messes up my datas as my separators are ";" too. How could I delete those rows (5 of them on 58000..) ?

I didn't find my answer in the search bar.

Thank you in advance,

Axel

```
'data.frame':   58792 obs. of  31 variables:
 $ title        : Factor w/ 55999 levels "-30-","...4 ...3 ...2 ...1 ...morte",..: 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 33 34 35 ...
 $ year         : num  85 53 55 110 89 114 116 116 101 31 ...
 $ length       : int  121 71 7 70 71 91 93 25 97 61 ...
 $ budget       : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ rating       : num  6.4 6 8.2 8.2 3.4 4.3 5.3 6.7 6.6 6 ...
 $ votes        : num  348 20 5 6 17 45 200 24 18 51 ...
 $ r1           : num  4.5 0 0 14.5 24.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 ...
 $ r2           : num  4.5 14.5 0 0 4.5 4.5 0 4.5 4.5 0 ...
 $ r3           : num  4.5 4.5 0 0 0 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 ...
 $ r4           : num  4.5 24.5 0 0 14.5 14.5 4.5 4.5 0 4.5 ...
 $ r5           : num  14.5 14.5 0 0 14.5 14.5 24.5 4.5 0 4.5 ...
 $ r6           : num  24.5 14.5 24.5 0 4.5 14.5 24.5 14.5 0 44.5 ...
 $ r7           : num  24.5 14.5 0 0 0 4.5 14.5 14.5 34.5 14.5 ...
 $ r8           : num  14.5 4.5 44.5 0 0 4.5 4.5 14.5 14.5 4.5 ...
 $ r9           : num  4.5 4.5 24.5 34.5 0 14.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 ...
 $ r10          : num  4.5 14.5 24.5 45.5 24.5 14.5 14.5 14.5 24.5 4.5 ...
 $ mpaa         : Factor w/ 8 levels "","0","14,5",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 8 1 1 1 ...
 $ Action       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Animation    : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Comedy       : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Drama        : int  1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ Documentary  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Romance      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Short        : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Action_C     : chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
 $ Animation_C  : chr  "No" "No" "Yes" "No" ...
 $ Comedy_C     : chr  "Yes" "Yes" "No" "Yes" ...
 $ Drama_C      : chr  "Yes" "No" "No" "No" ...
 $ Documentary_C: chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
 $ Romance_C    : chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
 $ Short_C      : chr  "No" "No" "Yes" "No" ...
```

Comment: you can replace the ";" into empty space or remove it.

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan Directly in the file you mean ? As it is an exercise, I think this it not allowed ...

Comment: After importing data set to R. you can replace the ;

Answer (score 1):

You should really include an example, but I think I can give you some code that should do what you want.

```
dat = data.frame(title = c("Babe", "Toy Story", "Mulan;"), rating = c(3,4,5))

> dat
      title rating
1      Babe      3
2 Toy Story      4
3    Mulan;      5

dat = dat[!grepl(";", dat$title), ]

> dat
      title rating
1      Babe      3
2 Toy Story      4
```

Comment: Thanks ! Now when I add this line of code, I have the error "Warning message:
In grepl(";", data$title) :
  la chaîne de caractères entrée 97 est incorrecte dans cet environnement linguistique". I found that this may be du to the encoding, but I don't really know how to deal with it ..

Comment: @AxelPHILIP add the head of your data file to the question. I need to see the data to fix it

Comment: I added it to the question. As you can see, I have strange values for "year" whereas in my csv file all years are 1975 or 2013 for example.

Comment: @AxelPHILIP I see. Is your file an excel file?

Comment: Yes, a .csv file more precisely.

Comment: @AxelPHILIP ok, so then you have comma separated values. Read in the data with read.csv and don't specify the sep.

Comment: In fact I have semicolon separated values (with some values equal to 4,5 for example). When using the read_csv command, I have an error indicating parsing failures.

Comment: @AxelPHILIP can you use excel's data tools to put those into column that will be easier to read into r?

Comment: I found another way to answer my question. I imported my file by clicking directly on 'Import dataset'. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting those lines in your csv file before reading it in as a dataframe.  Something like:

```
## first read in as text
x <- readLines('file.csv')

## I counted 31 columns in your data--assuming that's correct, remove lines that don't 
## have 30 semicolons
xClean <- x[sapply(gregexpr(';', x), function(n) length(n) == 30)]

## now read the cleaned text to a data.frame
dat <- read.table(text = xClean, sep = ';', header = TRUE)
```

### Edit:

It seemed to me like perhaps it would be more helpful to include a cleaned version of those problematic rows instead of deleting them outright.  To clean and include them, this would hopefully work:

```
x <- readLines('file.csv')

xSplit <- strsplit(x, ';')
xClean <- sapply(xSplit, function(s) {
    paste(paste(s[0:(length(s) - 30)], collapse = ' '),
          paste(s[(length(s) - 29):length(s)], collapse = ';'), 
          sep = ';')
})

dat <- read.table(text = xClean, sep = ';', header = TRUE)
```